# Is there any evidence that better sleep reduces the symptoms of chronic severe Fibromyalgia?

Tags: sleep, pain, serotonin

Is there any evidence that better sleep reduces the symptoms of chronic severe Fibromyalgia?

Severe fibromyalgia has been linked to the possible depletion of serotonin through prolonged and persistent sleep deprivation. Is this clinically proven and is there evidence that serotonin will intermediate to reduce the cycle of sleep loss, low serotonin production, chronic muscular pain, back to sleep loss?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.verywell.com/serotonin-in-fibromyalgia-chronic-fatigue-syndrome-716052